# how to get other field value from mysql DB using Jquery and CI4 after select onchange

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-4

So I have 3 select fields. I want it to be connected each time I select product code 1st, then it will show list of product SKU connected to 1st selected option. I tried using onchange, but it couldn't connect. I can get the id of the product_code, but I'm confused to connect product_sku with the same id of product_code. Kindly advise.

[image]

What I tried so far :

**Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class ProductModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'm_product';
    protected $allowedFields = ['s_product_code', 'slug', 's_product_sku', 's_product_var'];
}
```

and

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class IncomingModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'goods_in';
    protected $allowedFields = ['n_qty_in'];
}
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controllers\Inv;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\InvModel;
use App\Models\IncomingModel;
use App\Models\SizeModel;
use App\Models\ColorModel;
use App\Models\ProductModel;

class Incoming extends BaseController
{
    protected $InvModel;
    protected $IncomingModel;
    protected $SizeModel;
    protected $ColorModel;
    protected $ProductModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->IncomingModel = new IncomingModel();
        $this->InvModel = new InvModel();
        $this->SizeModel = new SizeModel();
        $this->ColorModel = new ColorModel();
        $this->ProductModel = new ProductModel();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Incoming Goods'
        ];
        return view('inv/incoming', $data);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $color = $this->ColorModel->findAll();
        $size = $this->SizeModel->findAll();
        $product = $this->ProductModel->findAll();

        $data = [
            'title' => 'Insert Incoming Goods',
            'color' => $color,
            'size' => $size,
            'product' => $product,
        ];
        return view('inv/incominginsert', $data);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?= $this->extend('layout/template'); ?>

<?= $this->section('content'); ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <h3 class="my-3">Insert Incoming Goods</h3>
            <form action="/inv/incoming/add" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <?php csrf_field(); ?>
                <fieldset id="fieldset">
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="product_code">Product Code</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="product_code" name="product_code" style="width: 80%;">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <?php foreach ($product as $c) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $c['id']; ?>"><?= $c['s_product_code']; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="product_sku">Product SKU</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="product_sku" name="product_sku" style="width: 60%;" disabled>
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <?php # foreach ($product as $c) : 
                            ?>
**//don't want it like this..**
                            <!-- <option value="<?= $c['id']; ?>"><?= $c['s_product_sku']; ?></option> -->

                            <?php # endforeach; 
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="variant_code">Variant Code</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="variant_code" name="variant_code" style="width: 60%;" disabled>
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <?php foreach ($product as $c) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $c['s_product_var']; ?>"><?= $c['s_product_var']; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="size">Size</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="size" name="size" style="width: 60%;">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <?php foreach ($size as $s) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $s['id']; ?>"><?= $s['s_size_name']; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="color">Color</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="color" name="color" style="width: 60%;">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <?php foreach ($color as $c) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $c['id']; ?>"><?= $c['s_color_description']; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <label for="qty_in" style="color: forestgreen; vertical-align: middle; justify-content: center;">Incoming Qty</label>
                    <div class="form-group input-group mb-3" style="width: 40%;">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Incoming Qty Pieces" min="1" step="1" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" title="Numbers only">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Pcs</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style=" float: right; margin-top: 5px;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#size').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap-5',
            placeholder: '-- Please Select Size --',
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        });

        $('#color').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap-5',
            placeholder: '-- Please Select Color --',
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        });

        $('#product_code').select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap-5',
            placeholder: '-- Please Select Product Code --',
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        });

        $('#product_code').on('change', function() {
            $('#product_sku').removeAttr("disabled");
            var id = $(this).val();

**//stuck from here..** 

        });

    });
</script>

<?= $this->endSection(); ?>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want fields 2 and 3 to be dynamically filled whenever field 1 selects an option. If that is the case, then you need to be making an AJAX-like call to a server endpoint that can deliver you that data; then use JS/JQuery/whatever to dynamically update the HTML client-side. This call would likely be executed from within the `onchange` event you're stuck on.

Comment: @parttimeturtle yeah that's correct.. I'm still trying to call using AJAX.